# Does the value of an attribute from another file get computed when I call it?

Tags: python

I was not really sure how to word this question. So I apologize for the confusion.

I'm a beginner in Python, so let me explain the question:
So, there is a dictionary named FEATURES being used from another file. This is the usage:

```
if (feature_name, dataset_id) in FEATURES.keys():
  ...
  ...
```

In the other file, FEATURES is defined as the following:

```
FEATURES = populate_features()
```

So my question is: when FEATURES.keys() is used in the first file, will populate_features() be invoked first to populate the dictionary? or will FEATURES be an empty dictionary since populate_features() was not invoked?

Note: poplulate_features() fills the dictionary up. So if it was not invoked, FEATURES would be an empty dictionary.

Comment: As long as you are importing `FEATURES` from the other file, you can expect the `populate_features` to be invoked

Comment: I'm really not being glib.  Why are you asking StackOverflow when you could just try it out on your own and see what happens?

Comment: Don't use `in FEATURES.keys()`, just `in FEATURES`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `import` a file, all its code runs.

```
foo = ["f", "o", "o"]

def foobar():
    print("foobar")
```

In the above example, the `foo` variable gets initialized, but `foobar` does not print anything as the function is just defined, but not called.

For your example, your `FEATURES` does get initialized on `import`, so way before you use it.

This is also the reason I'd strongly recommend not doing many things in initializing variables, like connecting to servers, reading configuration files, or such. As these things happen during import, this can make testing a pain.